# How do browsers handle unrecognized at-rules?

Tags: css, cross-browser

[CSS at-rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#at-rules) (e.g., `@import`) have existed since CSS2. New rules are slowly being added to CSS3 such as [`@supports`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports) with varying levels of browser support. How do the major browsers handle unsupported rules they don't recognize? Are they just ignored? Or are they treated as syntax errors?

E.g., if I were to use the `@supports` at-rule which is not supported by any version of IE, would IE fail with a syntax error, or would it be silently ignored?

```
@supports (pointer-events: none) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS 2.1 spec says

> ## [4.2 Rules for handling parsing errors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#parsing-errors)
>
> **At-rules with unknown at-keywords.**
>
> User agents must [ignore](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#ignore) an invalid at-keyword together with everything following it, up to the
>   end of the block that contains the invalid at-keyword, or up to and
>   including the next semicolon (;), or up to and including the next
>   block ({...}), whichever comes first.
>
> For example, consider the following:
>
> ```css
> @three-dee {
>   @background-lighting {
>     azimuth: 30deg;
>     elevation: 190deg;
>   }
>   h1 { color: red }
> }
> h1 { color: blue }
> ```
>
> The `@three-dee` at-rule is not part of CSS 2.1. Therefore, the whole
>   at-rule (up to, and including, the third right curly brace) is
>   [ignored](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#ignore). A CSS 2.1 user agent [ignores](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#ignore) it, effectively reducing the
>   style sheet to:
>
> ```css
> h1 { color: blue }
> ```